# Index inside a table postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I am transferring from mySQL to postgreSQL and wondering how can I add index inside the table of postgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  game_history
(
 id SERIAL,
 PRIMARY KEY(id),
 INDEX fk_game_history_user_idx (game_id ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT fk_game_history_user
 FOREIGN KEY (game_id )
 REFERENCES mydb.game (id)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

FROM

```
   INDEX fk_game_history_user_idx (game_id ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT fk_game_history_user
 FOREIGN KEY (game_id )
 REFERENCES mydb.game (id)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

I am not sure on this.

Answer (score 3):

You need a separate `create index` statement and you need to define a `game_id` column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  game_history
(
 id      SERIAL,
 game_id integer not null, -- you need to define the column
                           -- otherwise you can't have a foreign key
 PRIMARY KEY(id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_game_history_user
   FOREIGN KEY (game_id)
   REFERENCES game (id)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE INDEX fk_game_history_user_idx
  ON game_history (game_id ASC);
```

More details about the `create table` statement are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

And more details about the `create index` statement: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html

Comment: Since the Primary Key and Foreign Key are each on a single column, you can put them further inline as `id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` and `game_id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_game_history_user REFERENCES game (id)`, respectively.